# Past-Tense of the Verb "CC"

Tags: verbs, past-tense

I commonly use the verb "CC" (carbon copy). I know I could use the word "copy" instead, but I prefer to say "CC" (pronounced see-see).  For example, I might say (and have told my co-workers):

> I will CC you on that email.

But **what's the past tense of the verb CC?** Is it "CCed" (which seems strange)? I find that to be strange, so I usually apostrophe it to "CC'd" (which draws more attention to the strangeness).

And no, I don't want to say "copied."

Please provide proof in the form of a similar case with a different strange verb (eg. google => googled).

Comment: Analogy with a different verb can be useful for illustration, but isn’t really something the kind of “proof” one should look for — insofar as there’s any gold standard of proof in language, it’s usage data.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The OED gives the past tense of the verb *cc* (which it says is also spelled *CC*) as *cc’d* or *cced*. There are two citations for *cc’d* (1990, 2005) and one of *cced* (2000).

It also gives the past tense of *OK* as *OK’ed, OK-ed,* or *OKed*, but says nothing more about it.

Comment: I suspect an interesting history exists with regards to an apostrophe being used in place of commonly expected letters. Contractions and words such as _O'_ see apt. More recently, many tech terms get _'d_ -- CC'd being the current example.

Comment: OED is great. I'm not surprised in retrospect that they have a guideline for this.

Answer (score 6):

*CC'd* or *carbon copied* should be fine.  I don't find either strange.

For analogy, consider *OK'd* (also *okayed*).

Comment: I think "courtesy copy" as opposed to "carbon copy" is a more in vogue expansion with email being so prevalent.

Comment: The meaning of Cc and Bcc are defined in the technical specification for electronic mail (RFC 5322, which obsoletes RFC 2822, which obsoletes RFC 822).
The "Cc:" field (where the "Cc" means "Carbon Copy" in the sense of making a copy on a typewriter using carbon paper) contains the addresses of others who are to receive the message, though the content of the message may not be directed at them.
The "Bcc:" field (where the "Bcc" means "Blind Carbon Copy") contains addresses of recipients of the message whose addresses are not to be revealed to other recipients of the message.